# Проблема с получением кода через Телеграмм для PyCharn (Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pycharm

Здравия. Решил создать бота Телеграмма через Pycharm. Всё бы ничего, но при авторизации самого бота в процессе запрашиваемого номера телефона после его ввода выводит следующую ошибку:

```css
BadMsgNotification: [17] The msg_id is too high, the client time has to be synchronized.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Программы\Test_Setting.py", line 18, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\run.py", line 84, in run
    self.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 62, in start
    await self.authorize()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py", line 359, in authorize
    sent_code = await self.send_code(self.phone_number)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\auth\send_code.py", line 79, in send_code
    return types.SentCode._parse(r)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyrogram\types\authorization\sent_code.py", line 58, in _parse
    type=enums.SentCodeType(type(sent_code.type)),
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'BadMsgNotification' object has no attribute 'type'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Тот самый отрезок кода для бота Телеграмма на котором я остановился:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

#instantiante
from pyrogram import Client

config = ConfigParser()
# Читаем существующий файл
config.read('config.ini')

# Читаем значения из раздела
api_id = config.get('pyrogram', 'api_id')
api_hash = config.get('pyrogram', 'api_hash')


app = Client(name='my_account', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)


app.run()
```